# How do I perform a dynamic binding between a model and a class variable in Angular 2?

Tags: angular

I have a search page with a details component on it.

```
<p>
  Enter the cat name: <input #catName id='cat-name'>
  <button (click)="search(catName.value)">Search</button>
</p>

<div *ngIf="cat">
  <app-cat-details [cat]="cat"></app-cat-details>
</div>
```

When you type a name into the search page, and press search, it will do a http get and return a `Cat` object. I store this Cat object in a variable in the `.ts` file of the search page.

```
cat: Cat;
```

The details component below will then be shown and you can see the details. The details component looks like this:

```
<h2>Cat Details</h2>
<label>Name</label>   {{catDetailsModel.cat.Name}}<br>
<label>Colour</label>   {{catDetailsModel.cat.Colour}}<br>
<label>Price</label><input required #price [(ngModel)]="cdmadatDetailsModel.price" /><br>
```

So when you search the first time, the cat details appear. The details page has its own model, called CatDetailsModel, and one of the properties on it is a Cat, like this:

```
import { Cat } from "../entities/cat";

export class CatDetailsModel {
    cat: Cat;
    price: number;
    nextGroomingDate: Date;
}
```

The details component doesn't directly use the cat. It has the cat as a class variable:

```
@Input()
cat: Cat;
```

So that it can receive this from the search page. But instead of the details using that to put the information on the page, I use the model. Since the cat is on the model, I have to set up the model like this:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.catDetailsModel = new CatDetailsModel();
    this.catDetailsModel.cat = this.cat;
  }
```

This means when you first do a search, the page works fine because when the details are shown it runs nginit and sets up the view model and assigns the cat.

However if you do a subsequent search, `ngOnInit` does not run again. What I wanted was for the binding between the cat on the model and the local cat variable to be connected so when one updates, the other updates, however it does not.

I'm not sure how to make the details page be dynamic because of the extra step of the view model containing the cat. If it was bound directly to the cat object it would probably update fine.

I am unsure if this is a bad thing to do in angular, if I should simply have two models on the page rather than combining it into a single view model like you would do in MVC, or if I am just missing a way to make the model refresh when the cat refreshes from the user doing another search.

Comment: You might want to use `ngOnChanges()` which is called every time an `@Input()` was updated.

Comment: Don't use ngOnChanges. It would work but it's far from elegant and is bad practice.  No offense. Since javascript is based on reference unless they are pointing to the same object or value , they will not listen for eachother however,  you may use rxjs observables to watch for changes and update accordingly. It's a little bit of a learning curve but it's kind of a big deal to learn how to use them.

Comment: I agree that the smooth observable nature of angular is better than forcing updates through method calls, I will check out rxjs and see if I can figure it out